# Add values in column if row contains "Y"

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

[image: Current G-Sheet]

This is for keeping a record of Fantasy Football scores for all players that someone chooses over the season. In the WK (week) column each week a value will be entered.
At the bottom for eack WK I only want to add to the total score IF the Value in the In Squad column equals Y.
Is this possible please and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

> I only want to add to the total score IF the Value in the In Squad column equals Y. Is this possible please and if so how?

The solution is contained in the use of `COUNTIF` as outlined in the attached [Editors help sheet](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

## SUMIF

You will want to use the [SUMIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583) function to add values based on a condition.  If there are multiple conditions, use the [SUMIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496) function instead.

###### SUMIF Syntax

```
=SUMIF(range, criterion, [sum_range])
```

###### Sample Formula

```
=SUMIF($B$2:$B$8,"Y",C2:C8)
```

[image]

You could then copy the formula from **`C9`** to the **`WK#`** columns, `D9:F9` in the example, if you wanted to apply the same criteria there as well.
[image]

### Single Formula: BYCOL

Using a single formula is often easier to maintain than many copied formulas.  The formula could calculate the necessary column totals using [BYCOL](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12571032) to pass each column in turn into a [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) that would apply the same formula to each of them using the variable `col` (arbitrarily named) to represent the 'current' column.

The formula could be set to either

1. Apply [SUMIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583) to 'all' columns, based on the same condition; or
2. only apply [SUMIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583) to the `Total` column, but [SUM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669) the `WK#` columns.

###### 1.   SUMIF 'All' Columns

```
=BYCOL(C2:F8, LAMBDA(col, SUMIF($B$2:$B$8,"Y",col)))
```

###### 2.   SUMIF 'Total' Column, SUM WK# Columns

```
=BYCOL(C2:F8, LAMBDA(col,
   IF(COLUMN(C2)=COLUMN(col),
      SUMIF($B$2:$B$8,"Y",col),SUM(col))))
```

**<sub>SUMIF 'All' Columns</sub>**
[image]
 
**<sub>SUMIF 'Total' Column, SUM WK# Columns</sub>** 
[image]